# How to PUSH local branch develop to remote branch develop_1

Tags: git, push, git-remote

I have 2 remotes: origin and bit and local repository.
I want to pull from origin branch develop to local, and then from local push it to remote bit but branch develop2. I've tried:

```
git switch develop
git pull origin 
git push bit develop2
```

How to do it???

Answer (score 0):

I think i get it done by:

`git push bit develop:develop2`

Comment: Yes, that should do it.